# How to get version of static framework from info.plist? or any other way?

Tags: ios, nsbundle

I want to get version number from static libraries "info.plist".

I tried

```
NSString *strVersion = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",kCFBundleVersionKey]];
```

and

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:self.class] infoDictionary];
```

and

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"SDKInfo" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

But still, it returns either nil or the adopter app's info dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

Try this Code:

Objective-C

```
NSDictionary* infoDict = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSString* version = [infoDict objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
NSString* version = [infoDict objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```

Hope, it would help you.

Comment: It works for the app!! I want info of static library.